# Install Ruby 1.9.2 on Snow Leopard

Tags: ruby, rvm

I'm trying to install Ruby 1.9.2 on Snow Leopard and the infamous problem arose. I'm saying famous because I found lot of similar problems on the web, but no solution worked for me yet.

Upon trying to install from RVM or compiling directly, I get lot of warnings like this

```
tcltklib.c:8143: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
```

and at the end this error

```
/usr/local/lib/libsqlite3.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64) for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I tried setting the ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" in the .bash_profile file, and reinstalling sqlite3.

Any idea?

Comment: did you try adding -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 to CFLAGS in your Makefile after you ran configure? think its on line 50 for me

Comment: Oh thanks. I stopped on that matter sometime ago, since I'm ordering new Macbook soon, I kept on going with what I have. But I will try that when I get the new MB. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing sqlite3 as 64-bit as mentioned here:

http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2010/07/08/installing-ruby-1-9-2-with-rvm-on-snow-leopard/